# Property injection with Autofac and ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-5.0, property-injection

My controller classes have a single dependency, e.g.:

```cs
public class UserController : ControllerBase {
  public UserController(IMediator mediator) => _mediator = mediator;
  private readonly IMediator _mediator;
}
```

But that must be duplicated in all my controllers. I'd prefer to do property injection, so I could clean it up like this:

```cs
public abstract class MyControllerBase : ControllerBase {
  public IMediator Mediator { get; init; }  // use init so container resolves this and cannot be changed later
}

public class UserController : MyControllerBase {
}
```

To get that working, I followed [the docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services).

I changed my `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
```

And I registered controllers in `Startup.ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)`:

```cs
builder
  .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
  .AssignableTo<MyControllerBase>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
  .PropertiesAutowired();
```

That works.

However the [docs say](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html?highlight=PropertiesAutowired#property-injection) that I can inject a specific property:

> If you have one specific property and value to wire up, you can use the WithProperty() modifier: `builder.RegisterType<A>().WithProperty("PropertyName", propertyValue);`

So I have to change my code:

```cs
var types =
  typeof(Startup).Assembly
  .GetExportedTypes()
  .Where(type => typeof(MyControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
  .ToArray();

foreach (var type in types)
  builder.RegisterType(type).WithProperty(nameof(MyControllerBase.Mediator), propertyValue);
```

How can I dynamically resolve `propertyValue` from the container. AND, will the container inject any other properties in controller classes, or would it inject that one only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do wasn't meant for that scenario.
As you have already encountered, it for if the specific value is known at the time of setup not about dynamic resolution.

I suggest leaving it the way it was working before where the container will resolve the dependency and set the property.

```
//...

public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder) { 
    var types =
        typeof(Startup).Assembly
        .GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(type => typeof(MyControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        .ToArray();
    
    
    builder.RegisterTypes(types).PropertiesAutowired();
}
```

The approach you want to take is really unnecessary given your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Could you please tell me, supposing I do it the way I described, am I right in assuming that the container would only provide that one dependency - if the base class has any other properties they wouldn't be resolved, and it would fail silently at runtime? At least using `PropertiesAutowired` it would fail at startup if there's a problem?

Comment: Also the registration code you wrote differs from mine (`builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes() ....`) - any reason or is it just a personal preference?